# WPF Creating an instance of a class in xaml

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have a problem with creating the instance of a class in xaml file. I thought you can do it like this:

```
<src:MyDataClass x:Key="data"/>
```

in the resource part of the user control and then use it in the xaml file (for example bind to it).

But even tough the class I created is located in the same namespace it says that:

> "The type was not found. Verfiy that all assemblies were built, etc".

How to get it right? is there another method?

Thanks for suggestions.

Comment: how did you declare the `src` XML namespace ?

Answer (score 1):

Well obviously you have to add the right namespace to your xaml. The namespace which contains the class you want instantiate. After reading [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms747086.aspx), you should be able to solve your problem.