# How to specify datacontext in WPF?

Tags: wpf

I have a class in the ViewModel folder called "MainViewModel", and I want my datacontext to be set to the class. I am doing it the following way, somehow it doesnt seem to work. Does anyone have some ideas? Thanks.

```
    xmlns:ViewModel="clr-namespace:***.***.ViewModel"
<MenuItem Header="always visible" DataContext="{Binding ViewModel:MainViewModel}"  IsCheckable="True" IsChecked="{Binding  MenuVisible}"  />
```

Many thanks.

Comment: To the class or to an object of the class?

Comment: What do you want the instance to come from?

Answer (score 1):

As Tim has already noted, you are setting the class definition as your `DataContext` and not an instance. The example he gave sets the instance in XAML, which is perfectly accurate and gets the job done; however, in my experience you usually have the instance in your code-behind already. To set the `DataContext`, you would do something along the lines of:

```
myMenuItem.DataContext = myMainViewModelInstance;
```

Answer (score 0):

You're setting the class as your datacontext, not an instance of the class. Declare an instance as in the example in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3048127/wpf-creating-an-instance-of-a-class-in-xaml) and bind to it.